Identifying the Correct Boolean Expression for a False Outcome
Argument 1
Premise 1: Some x is g : XG
Premise 2: John is x : JX
Conclusion: John is g : J⇒JG
The full expression:
XG∧JX⇒J⇒JG
In Boolean algebra, I am constructing this argument incorrectly, as the full expression I created results in 1, whereas the correct outcome should be a fallacy (false).
What would be the correct expression for this argument to yield a fallacy?
